# How do I add the Internet Archive as a music source to Rhythmbox?

Tags: music, rhythmbox, source

I tried Banshee once and it had an Internet Archive plugin that was great. Can I add the Internet Archive as a source in Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is an Ampache plug-in for Rhytmbox, if you are thinking about accessing Ampache music servers. Otherwise, you could always just install Banshee, as it should be available in the archives / software center.